# How to get raw preview data from Camera object at least 33 frames per second in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, preview

Our target device is Samsung Galaxy P2 , and to transmit video we need to have fps is 33 , i.e. 33 frame per second, below is the code what i am using,

```
 List<int[]> supportedPreviewFps=parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
```

Output of this function was 4000 & 35000 , i believe that means, device is supporting 4 frame per sec to 33 frame per seconds,

Now i could do the setFrameRange using below API,

```
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(4000,35000);
```

As it was supporting only this value, and i am getting frame at the gap of 110 ms, i believe, to have 33 fps, the interval should be 30 -- 33 ,

any idea, what to be done ?

Comment: How are you processing the image preview? It could be keeping the device busy.

Comment: Even i am not doing anything, then also same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the device running out of CPU.
The preview callback is rather software intensive, particularly if you ask for a non-native format.

Try using

```
  adb shell
  $ vmstat -d 1
```

and look at the amount of idle CPU. If it's zero (or less than ~ 5%), then that's probably where the issue lies.

This isn't easy to mitigate: The only way I'm aware of is to use a SurfaceTexture instead and do as much processing as possible in the GPU.